# Chrome extension active tab and console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first chrome extension and I just want to start with a simple thing: grabbing the url and showing it in console.log(). The problem is when I click that button, nothing is logged.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Copy Title and URL",
  "description": "This extension will copy the title and url of an article",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Copy Title & URL</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="copyUrl">Copy Title + URL</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var copyURLButton = document.getElementById('copyUrl');
  copyURLButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      console.log(tab.url);
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the console you're looking in is wrong, as your code seems fine (except for using deprecated `getSelected()`, you should switch to `query()`)

To access the popup's console, you need to right-click your extension's button and select "Inspect popup".

Answer (score 1):

Awesome, I seem to have been looking at the wrong console. I changed the code to query below.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var copyURLButton = document.getElementById('copyUrl');
  copyURLButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
      console.log(tabs[0].url);
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```