# Firefox extension: JavaScript file included via script tag is not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Based on the [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension), I've created my own extension that showing just a 'hi' message. I've included a file named "popup.js" via  tag. But this file is not getting executed. 
This is my **manifest.json** file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Ext",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Shows a hi message.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/ff.jpg"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/toggle-off.png",
    "default_title": "EXT",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  }
}
```

This is my **popup.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hi</h2>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is only a single line in my popup.js file. That is,

```
console.warn("This is a warning");
```

But I can't see anything in the console. The pop-up is showing properly when I click on the extension icon. 
I don't know what am missing here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your message is printed in the console. Just not the current page's console. The popup has it own one.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for that information. It's new info for me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649411/934239 for a Chrome answer; for Firefox, it's similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find out what was the issue.
To execute the code from the js file included via  tag you need to specify that code in `browser.tabs.executeScript` and there is an error in my manifest.json file. I should specify the permission as `activeTab` instead of `tabs`.
So my modified **manifest.json** file is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Ext",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Shows a hi message.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/ff.jpg"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/toggle-off.png",
    "default_title": "EXT",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  }
}
```

and my **popup.js** file becomes:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({code: `console.warn("This is a warning")`});
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) for more details.